# Nonzero function argument becomes zero inside function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a C#/Unity project using 64-bit Ubuntu 18.04. I have two non-static classes, `ClassA` and `ClassB`, and inside the instance method `classA.Foo()`, there are two calls to the `public static int` method `ClassB.Floor(float x)`. In one of the two places where `Foo` calls `Floor`, if I follow the stack trace of values passed from `classA.Foo` to `ClassB.Floor`, nonzero inputs from `Foo` become 0 inside `Floor` before any computation happens.

I've searched stackoverflow, stackexchange, and google in general for people who have had problems with variables changing from nonzero to 0 when passed into functions, either in C# or another language. I found some results regarding passing reference vs. value types, but `ClassB.Floor` is receiving a float and returning an int. I've confirmed that values of the proper type (non-double floats) are being input to `ClassB.Floor`.

`ClassB.Floor` is defined as

```cs
public class ClassB : MonoBehaviour {
    [...]

    public static int Floor(float x) {
        int xi = (int)x;
        return x < xi ? xi - 1 : xi;
    }
}
```

Example with debugger value comments:

```cs
public class ClassA {
    # Set somewhere else during initialization, but definitely
    # exists by the time `Foo` is called.
    private GameObject gameObject;

    [...]

    public byte Foo(Vector3 pos) {  # pos: "(-17f, 0f, 15f)"
        [...]

        int x = ClassB.Floor(pos.x);  # x: -17
        Vector3 objPosition = gameObject.transform.position;  # objPosition: "(-16f, 0f, 0f)"
        float xx = objPosition.x;  # xx: -16f
        int px = ClassB.Floor(xx);  # px: 0

        [...]
    }
}
```

So, the `px` value isn't being set correctly by `ClassB.Floor`, even though it's working correctly in the calculation of `x`. Moreover, if I go into the debugger and follow the program flow from `int px = ClassB.Floor(xx);` in `classA.Foo` into `ClassB.Floor`, I immediately see this:

```cs
public static int Floor(float x) {  # x: 0
```

And the output value of 0 is correctly computed from that input of 0.  If I use Rider's debugger's Evaluate Expression functionality at any point during program execution after `xx` is defined, `ClassB.Floor(xx)` returns the correct value of `-16` even though the program itself does not.

No errors or warnings are generated in the course of program flow through this part of the code. Does anybody have any idea what could be causing this? I am really baffled. Thanks in advance!

[Update] Here is a more minimal example demonstrating the same behavior. `ClassB.Floor` does not seem to matter at all:

```cs
public class ClassA {
    public byte Foo(Vector3 pos) {  # pos: "(-17f, 0f, 15f)"
        float xx = -16f;  # xx: -16f
        int px = Mathf.FloorToInt(xx);  # px: 0
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Same deal: If I step into `Mathf.FloorToInt`, defined as

```cs
public static int FloorToInt(float f)
{
  return (int) Math.Floor((double) f);
}
```

I find that `f=0` from the start of the function, even though `xx=-16f`.

Comment: To me what you're experiencing is odd. Your Floor function doesn't depend on any state and it's working fine tested locally. The only concern I have is with `gameObject.transform.position`, because though it seems filled with correct values the only possibility is that line `float xx` doesn't hold the correct value or its value is lost doing that implicit cast, but it seems impossible as X member of Vector3 is a float as well...

Comment: @AlbertoSolano Agreed. I confirmed it was working correctly by inserting `Debug.Log(xx is float + " " + xx is double)` after the creation of `xx`, and got `True False` as expected. So one way or another, `xx` seems to be a normal float before it's passed as an argument into `ClassB.Floor`.

I probably also should have noted - I get the same behavior when `ClassB.Floor` is replaced with `Mathf.FloorToInt`, so the problem may not lie with `ClassB` at all.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly fine for me :

```
public class ClassB : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start(){
        ClassA instance = new ClassA(gameObject);
        instance.Foo(new Vector3(10.5f,15.2f,20.8f));
    }
    public static int Floor(float x) // 10.5f and 12.19f
    {
        int xi = (int)x;
        return x < xi ? xi - 1 : xi;
    }
}


public class ClassA
{
    private GameObject gameObject;
    public ClassA(GameObject go){
        gameObject = go;
    }
    public byte Foo(Vector3 pos) // new Vector3(10.5f,15.2f,20.8f)
    {
        int x = ClassB.Floor(pos.x);  // 10
        //Debug.Log(x);
        Vector3 objPosition = gameObject.transform.position; // new Vector3(12.19f, 1f, -10f);
        float xx = objPosition.x; // 12.19f
        int px = ClassB.Floor(xx); //12
        //Debug.Log(px);
        return new byte();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, and in fact I can remove the `Vector3` game object position, set `xx` to some float literal like `16f` and use `Mathf.FloorToInt` instead of my custom `Floor` and I get the same result. I'm really confused how this could be happening. Thanks for trying out a complete example though! I'm worried it's some horrible system bug.

Comment: @heyitsguay During writing this code, I actually copied ```ClassB.Floor(pos.x);``` to not write it twice, and positioned it after ```int px``` however, I forgot to change ```pos.x``` to ```xx```, and I got the same thing as you got. maybe you have mispronounced something in your actual code.

Comment: Possible, though I've looked closely. [EDIT] Tried posting the method code, I see comments aren't formatted for code blocks. Anyway, the issue still happens when I replace the method body with the updated minimal example I added to my original question.

Comment: @heyitsguay do you use Debug.Log to follow xx and px values?

Comment: Yes. I get the same values as indicated in the example comments above.

Comment: @heyitsguay did you try to create a new project and test there just in case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194269/discussion-between-mohammad-zamanian-and-heyitsguay).